# Modify css using jquery

Tags: jquery, click

How do I change a css property using jquery in the following example?. What I need to do is to change the background position of the "btn1" class when the user click that item. I'm not able to target the "btn1" class with the "click" function...not an expert by the way

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="loadListaClientes(1);loadClientWeb(1);loadSlideWeb(1);return false;" class="btn1"></a>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="loadListaClientes(2);loadClientGr(1);return false;" class="btn2"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="loadListaClientes(3);loadClientAds(1);return false;" class="btn3"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="loadListaClientes(4);loadClientPh(1);return false;" class="btn4"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="loadListaClientes(5);loadClientMo(1);return false;" class="btn5"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="loadListaClientes(6);loadClientApp(1);return false;" class="btn6"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#" onclick="loadListaClientes(7);loadClientId(1);return false;" class="btn7"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ps: I update the markup

Comment: Why are you using inline `onclick` when you're using jQuery (with a (rather awesome) click-handling method)? Oh, and your HTML is horribly invalid, the *only* valid child of `ul` or `ol` is an `li` element. Wrap the `a` inside of an `li`.

Comment: If you mention what the different background positions are for each button, I will update my answer to show them.

Comment: Actually I found that "css('background-position', 'bottom') will work for any size. I'm having a problem now cause it works in the fiddle but it doesn't in my source files

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I do recommend using delegation rather than a click handler for each menu item, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$("a.btn1").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css('background-position', 'new_values_here');
});
```

Also if you're using a list `<ul>` you better use its' items `<li>`.. Otherwise it makes no semantic sense.

Comment: I've added this: 
$("a.btn1").on("click", function() { $(this).css('background-position', '-20'); }); 

And add the li tag as you said, but still not working...Do I miss something?

Comment: I guess I need to add some fuctionality in order to reset the background position of all others links (btn2, btn3, etc), right?.

Comment: There's something I don't understand yet: I have a class (btn1, btn2, etc) for each link with a background image and all images are different sizes, so I need to change the background position indivudaly. In the CSS of the jsfiddle you have styled the <a> insted the <btn1>, maybe that's the reason it won't work for me?.

Comment: I used `a` just for shortness because it's the only link in my jsfiddle  example, but you're free to use `.btn1` - http://jsfiddle.net/dQZ7r/1/

Comment: Still not working :(

HTML
 <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="loadListaClientes(1);loadClientWeb(1);loadSlideWeb(1);return false;" class="btn1"></a></li></ul></div>

SCRIPT
$("a.btn1").on("click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('background-position', 'bottom');
});

CSS
.btn1{
 background:url(../images/btn_web.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 ;
 width:50px;
 height:28px;
 float:left;
 margin-left:90px;
}

Comment: can you please update the fiddle example with the code you have?

Comment: It's working in the fiddle, don't know why, I just copy it from my files. The html (header) is embebed into my main index.php, that changes anything?

Comment: Do you have your jQuery in the header of the page? Or at the bottom?

Comment: the script is in the head section

Comment: then you need to wrap your code in the `.ready()` handler - `$(function() { ... });` http://api.jquery.com/ready/  Your DOM is simply not ready and the element you're trying to attach the listener to does not exist yet.

Comment: Now it's working!. Any idea how can I reset the background position for all the links, except the one I click ?.

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifies to your code and now it looks like [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/w83Pj/1/)

For making this wokring you should load jQuery in your project. I guess [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) is a good start

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="btn1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn3"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn4"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn5"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn6"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn7"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Add one click handler using delegation:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // wait for DOM load
    // handle click on menu
    $(".menu").on("click", "a", function(ev) { // delegate to menu div
        ev.preventDefault(); // similar to "return false"
        var button = $(this); // the "a" that was clicked
        var itemIndex = $(button.parent(), ".menu").index() + 1; // calculate element number
        loadListaClientes(itemIndex); // first function can be called using index
        // handle buttons case by case
        switch (itemIndex) {
        case 1:
            // ".btn1" handled here
            button.css('background-position', newPosition); // change background CSS
            loadClientWeb(1);
            loadSlideWeb(1)
            break;
        case 2:
            // ".btn2", etc.
            loadClientGr(1);
            break;
        case 3:
            loadClientAds(1);
            break;
        case 4:
            loadClientPh(1);
            break;
        case 5:
            loadClientMo(1);
            break;
        case 6:
            loadClientApp(1);
            break;
        case 7:
            loadClientId(1);
            break;
        default:
            // default menu action or throw error here
        }
    });
});
```